# Usage of で after みんな

Tags: grammar, particles

> これしかないから みんな**で**どうにかやってきたんだろう

In the sentence above, why after みんな, instead of particle は or particle が, particle で is used?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8107/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9730/9831 /  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44708/9831

Answer (score 0):

This で emphasizes cooperation unlike は, が.