# Use of noun/location before します

Tags: grammar

I am trying to understand the sentence for Wanikani:

> 二十一頁の二番はクラスでします

The translation given is:

> We will work on question 2 on page 21 in class.

Can someone explain the last part? i.e.クラスでします. I haven't come across any similar examples online.

Comment: Related (for で): [Why is particle で used instead of particle と in 家族で出かける (Kazoku de dekakeru)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/8107/43676)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 二十一頁の二番はクラスでします

Nothing too mysterious happening here.

The で simply marks where the action is taking place, i.e. **in** class.

します is just the polite from of する i.e. 'to do', which they have liberally translated as 'work on'. So a literal translation of the whole sentence would be "As for number two of page 21 we will do *it* in class.

**Edit**

As you can see from the comment chain my explanation of で as 'where' is controversial. In this case the more likely usage is "as a", i.e. クラスで = as a class. See the link provided by @aguijonazo

Comment: That's certainly one possible interpretation but doesn't seem very likely. Why would they move to a different place to solve this particular problem? I would understand this クラス as referring to a group of people, not a location. I would say 教室 if I mean a classroom.

Comment: I see your point but to me, in English at least, I see very little difference between 'in class' as a location and 'in class' as a group of people. I also don't see why で would imply movement. I can easily envisage a scenario where the teacher is telling the pupils what homework questions to do this evening and says that they will do this particular question in class (maybe it's a more difficult question). That seems like a perfectly legitimate and likely use to me. Happy to correct if I've failed to understand something here.

Comment: I am questioning your explication that で marks **where** the action is taking place. Why would you specify where you are going to solve Q2 in page 21 unless you solve other questions in some other place?

Comment: Well, I gave what I thought was a reasonable example with the homework scenario. Do you not think that is legitimate? If not I will change the answer.

Comment: As I said, your interpretation is possible. It just doesn’t seem very likely to me. If the teacher said クラスでします in your scenario, I would still understand クラス as a group of people, as opposed to each student doing it individually. If the teacher’s focus is on **where** that activity will take place, she would more likely say 教室.

Comment: I'm not trying to be awkward but I think this is interesting. If the teacher said to me "We will solve this in class" I would not think about the physical location but the collection of people, as you say. But paradoxically I would not expect there to be a group effort to solve the problem, but rather the teacher explaining how to solve it, so in that sense it would be the location. I guess it's no coincidence that で can express both concepts since there seems to be a degree of ambiguity. Anyway, I will edit the question. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: What I meant is it marks a broader setting in which a group of people are involved, not a place. Whether the teacher explains how to solve the question or the class try to solve it together is not important.

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous answer said, the クラスで means "in class" while the します is just a "do" do what? We are going to "do" question 2 on page 21, it sounds weird in english but the japanese do (する) is much more versatile and makes sense in this context.

If there's anything else you might have a doubt about just let me know.